# RVM: How to use gems from a different ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have been using RVM to manage my Rubies and gems.

When I first installed RVM, the Ruby version that I installed was `1.9.2-p0`. I recently installed Ruby `1.9.2-p136`, which created a new Ruby in the RVM.

My problem is I want to use the latest version of Ruby but all of the gems I installed were installed under the `1.9.2-p0` directory, because RVM keeps gems completely separate between Rubies, and I want to be able to use those gems with my new version, `p-136` without having to reinstall them all.

Is there a way I can get my gems from my `p-0` Ruby to work with my `p-136` Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check out [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/) and export your current gems.

```
rvm gemset export
```

Read the [gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets) docs for more information.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `copy` in rvm

```
$ rvm gemset copy 1.9.2-p0 1.9.2-p136
```

See more about the [rvm copy command](http://rvm.io/gemsets/copying/)

This is the fastest way to get your gems moved over and it wont reinstall everything, just copy them over. But once you've got that squared away I'd do as the others are suggesting and start using `gemsets`. It's a nice way to group the gems you use in your projects.

Comment: This is the most inefficient and ugly way I guess. It just used double space. They should just symlink the gems

Answer (score 5):

This might help: http://rvm.io/gemsets/initial/

Basically, if you setup a global gemset configuration, those gems will be used for every ruby version you install.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a gemset from one ruby to another.
[rvm copy](https://rvm.io/gemsets/copying)

```
$ rvm gemset copy 2.1.1@rails4 2.1.2@rails4
```